# Problem with .split() my program miscounts a certain input

Tags: python, split, try-except

We were tasked to create a program that counts the total numbers of unique words from a user input and we are not allowed to use sets and dictionaries. Words with duplicates or identical words should not be counted. I have a code and it works with other inputs but when I input "facebook face face book" or something similar it counts 3 instead of 2.

```
def unique_counter():
    words = input().lower().split()
    unique_words = {}
    for word in words:
        try:
             unique_words[word] += 1
        except KeyError:
             unique_words[word] = 1
    print(len(unique_words))


unique_counter()
```

[similar input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZF4l.png)
[input with correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBzIY.png)

Comment: it's because "facebook face face book" has THREE unique words

Comment: Also - you're using a dictionary

Comment: @Сергей Кох this is the whole code. It's just an exercise so it's not long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you can't use dictionaries, I would use the `in` operator.

```
def unique_counter():
    unique_words = []
    words = input().lower().split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in unique_words:
            unique_words.append(word)
    print(f"there are {len(unique_words)} unique words in the phrase")
```

if you have to check also substrings (you expect that the input "face facebook" gives "face" and "book" as unique words), then it's a bit more complicated.

if you have to count how many times that word is used, then it's pretty complex without using dictionaries.